# Need guidance to make small utility based on user inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, artificial-intelligence

I want to implement a small code I am not able to understand from where to start. I want to create a text field if user enter some text into text field I want to detect category of this text. For example if user enter "How to create an app for iOs".. utlity should detect this category as information technology. another example "good hotels in Singapore" this utility should detect treat this category as Travel....

Comment: What makes you think this is going to be "small"?

Comment: @bfavaretto Naivety. [But maybe that's not that bad of a start...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)

Comment: @bfavaretto - I know this is not small but just to start on somthing big....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea to create library with words.

```
var categories = new Object();
categories = {
'IT' : {'iOS', 'Android'},
'Travel' : {'USA', 'London', 'Singapore'}
};

var text = 'How to create an app for iOs';
var spitter = text.split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < spitter.length; i++) {
     var word = spitter[i];
     for (var categoryKey in categories) {
         for (var categoryKeyWord in categories[categoryKey])  {
            var regExp = new RegExp(categories[categoryKey][categoryKeyWord], i);
            if (regEpx.match(word) {
               //Your logic
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!!  I like your idea but need something more robust because I have just given two example list gonna be very - 2 long.....

Comment: This is just example. In real world you must have a database.